# Real life examples of methodologies and lifecycles

Tags: methodology

Choosing the correct lifecycle and methodology isn't as easy as it was before when there weren't so many methodologies, this days a new one emerges every day.

I've found that most projects require a certain level of evolution and that each project is different from the rest. That way, extreme programming works with for a project for a given company with 15 employees but doesn't quite work with a 100 employee company or doesn't work for a given project type (for example real time application, scientific application, etc).

I'd like to have a list of experiences, mostly stating the project type, the project size (number of people working on it), the project time (real or planned), the project lifecycle and methodology and if the project succeded or failed. Any other data will be appreciated, I think we might find some patterns if there's enough data. Of course, comments are welcomed.

- PS: Very large, PT: Very long, LC:
  Incremental-CMMI, PR: Success
- PS: Very large, PT: Very long, LC:
  Waterfall-CMMI, PR: Success

**Edit:** I'll be constructing a "summary" with the stats of all answers.

Comment: Could you correct the "lyfe-cycle" tag? ;)

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience:

- Project size: Very large (150+
  persons)
- Project time: Very long (+6 years)
- Project income (estimated): 40
  Million $ (Military is paying)
- Project life cycle: Incremental
  lyfetime. Main milestones every
  year.
- Project structure: Traditional at
  first (system department,
  development department, etc) not so
  good. Process based later (the
  process establish a flow of work,
  requirements, design,
  implementation, test, feedback,
  metrics): quite good so far.
- Project result: success (so far)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

- Project size: about 1 million lines of code, 30 people
- Project time: 9 years
- Project life cycle: good old waterfall, due to big customers requirements, but with staggered delivery to the QA team - it is very difficult to be agile when you have customers commitments to large clients
- Project structure: we are organized in departments but we use CMMI to keep them in sync - we have stakeholders, work products, deviance procedures, etc.
- Project result: we've really improved with the implementation of CMMI and have delivered our last few releases on time every time

-C.

Comment: Really, waterfall with a 9 year span, are you sure? Waterfall is not incremental, I mean, you deliver to the client once in waterfall model.